# Segmentation fault: 11 while trying to print array with 50k items

Tags: arrays, c, memory, calloc, fault

I'm trying to print array with 50k items into a file but it could be done only if I set small numbers of items, e.g. 5k.

```
void fputsArray(int *arr, int size, char *filename)
{
    char *string = (char*)calloc( (8*size+1), sizeof(char) );
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sprintf( &string[ strlen(string) ], "%d\n", arr[i] );

    FILE *output;
    char fullFilename[50] = "./";
    output = fopen(strcat(fullFilename, filename), "w");
    fputs(string, output);
    fclose(output);
    free(string);
}
```

*size* is 50000, defined in *#DEFINE*.
This is working code. But if I delete *8* multiplying to *size*, that is I supposed to be working, doesn't work. I got in that situation *Segmentation fault: 11*
Why should I allocate 8 times more memory than I need?

Comment: There are many places in your code where you don't check for null or overflows.  Try using a debugger and/or making your code robust .

Comment: If the loop is `size` and you are sprintfing integers, they will take up more than 1 byte each. So the `*8`.

Comment: The "8 times more memory than needed" comment is hard to understand; you are printing a minimum of `2*size+1` characters (a digit and the `\n`) and potentially up to `12*size+1` depending on the values of the integers .  It seems likely that the problem is writing off the end of the allocated space .

Comment: Why don't you just `fprintf` to the file?

Comment: The reason it may _appear_ to work with 5k and not 50k is that you probably didn't corrupt enough memory for the Operating System to notice.  Check how much your strlen increases after every number...

Comment: `output = fopen(strcat(fullFilename, filename), "w");` strcat() := red flag.

Comment: Why do you need to prepend `"./"` to `filename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the *input* to your function is all correct:

```
void fputsArray(int *arr, int size, char *filename)
```

Sizes should be given as `size_t`.

```
{
    char *string = (char*)calloc( (8*size+1), sizeof(char) );
```

The clearing of the memory (`calloc`) is unnecessary, `malloc` and setting `string[0] = '\0'` would suffice. `sizeof( char )` is always `1` by definition. And [you should not cast the result of an allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Actually, the whole construct is unnecessary, but that's for later.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sprintf( &string[ strlen(string) ], "%d\n", arr[i] );
```

Not actually that bad, aside from `string + strlen( string )` being simpler and that there should always be `{ }` surrounding the statement. Still unnecessarily complex.

```
    FILE *output;
    char fullFilename[50] = "./";
    output = fopen(strcat(fullFilename, filename), "w");
```

A filename is always relative to the current working directory, so the `"./"` is unnecessary. You *should* however have checked the filename length before `strcat`ing it into a static buffer like that.

```
    fputs(string, output);
```

Ah, but you have not checked *if the `fopen` actually succeeded!*

```
    fclose(output);
    free(string);
}
```

All in all, I've seen worse. Whether your numbers actually fit your buffer is guesswork, though, and most importantly *the whole memory shenanigans are unnecessary*.

Consider:

```
void printArray( int const * arr, size_t size, char const * filename )
{
    FILE * output = fopen( filename, "w" );
    if ( output != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        {
            fprintf( output, "%d\n", arr[i] );
        }
        fclose( output );
    }
    else
    {
        perror( "File open failed" );
    }
}
```

I think this is *much* better than trying to figure out where your memory guesswork went wrong.

---

**Edit:** On second thought, I would have that function take a `FILE *` argument instead of a filename, which would give you the flexibility of printing to an already-opened stream (like `stdout`) as well, and also let you do the error handling of the `fopen` in a place higher up that might have additional capabilities to give useful information.

Answer (score 1):

> size is 50000, defined in #DEFINE. This is working code. But if I delete 8 multiplying to size, that is I supposed to be working, doesn't work. I got in that situation Segmentation fault: 11 Why should I allocate 8 times more memory than I need?

You are writing about this size estimates:

```
    char *string = (char*)calloc( (8*size+1), sizeof(char) );
```

But the array in use is `int[]` and you will write one value per line in disk as in

```
    sprintf( &string[ strlen(string) ], "%d\n", arr[i] );
```

This seems unnecessary complicated. As for the size, assume all values as `INT_MIN`, a.k.a. (in `limits.h`)

```
#define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1)
```

for an 4-byte integer. So you have 11 chars. Just that. 10 digits plus one symbol for the signal. This will got you covered for any `int` value. Add 1 for the `'\n'`

But...

- Why use calloc() at all?
- Why not just use a `size * 12-byte` array that would fit every possible values?
- why declare a new `char*` to hold the value in `char` format instead of just using `fprintf()` at once?
- why `void` instead of just returning something like -1 for error or the number of itens written to disk in case of success?

#### Back to the program

If you really want to write down the array to disk in a single call to `fputs()`, holding the whole giant string in memory, consider that `sprintf()` returns the number of bytes written, so this is the value you need to use as a pointer to the output string...

If you want to use memory allocation you can do it in blocks. Considere that if all values are under 999 the 50.000 lines would have no more than 4 bytes each. But if all values are constant equal to `INT_MIN` you will have the max 12 bytes per line.

So you can use the return of `sprintf()` to update the pointer to the string, and use `realloc()` when needed, allocating, let's say, in blocks of a few K-bytes. (if you really want to to that write back and I can post an example)

#### C Example

The code below writes the file the way you tried to, and returns the total bytes written. It depends on the values of the array, anyway. The maximum is what I said, 12 bytes per line...

```
int fputsArray( unsigned size, int*  array , const char* filename)
{
    static char string[12 * MY_SIZE_ ] = {0};
    unsigned ix = 0; // pointer to the next char to use in string
    FILE*    output = fopen( filename, "w");
    if ( output == NULL ) return -1;
    // file is open
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+= 1)
    {
        unsigned used = sprintf( (string + ix), "%d\n", array[i] );
        ix += used;
    } 
    fputs(string, output);
    fclose(output);
    return ix;
}
```

#### Using `fprintf()`

This code writes the same file, using `fprintf()` and is way simpler...

```
int fputsArray_b( unsigned size, int*  array , const char* filename)
{
    unsigned ix = 0; // bytes written
    FILE*    output = fopen( filename, "w");
    if ( output == NULL ) return -1;
    // file is open
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+= 1)
        ix += fprintf( output, "%d\n", array[i]);
    fclose(output);
    return ix;
}
```

#### A complete test with the 2 functions

```
#define     MY_SIZE_ 50000
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fputsArray(const unsigned,int*,const char*);
int fputsArray_b(const unsigned,int*,const char*);

int main(void)
{
    int value[MY_SIZE_];
    srand(210726); // seed for today :)
    value[0] = INT_MIN; // just to test: this is the longest value
    for ( int  i=1; i<MY_SIZE_; i+=1 ) value[i] = rand();
    int used = fputsArray( MY_SIZE_, value, "test.txt");
    printf("%d bytes written to disk\n", used );

    used = fputsArray_b( MY_SIZE_, value, "test_b.txt");
    printf("%d bytes written to disk using the alternate function\n", used );
    return 0;
}


int fputsArray( unsigned size, int*  array , const char* filename)
{
    static char string[12 * MY_SIZE_ ] = {0};
    unsigned ix = 0; // pointer to the next char to use in string
    FILE*    output = fopen( filename, "w");
    if ( output == NULL ) return -1;
    // file is open
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+= 1)
    {
        unsigned used = sprintf( (string + ix), "%d\n", array[i] );
        ix += used;
    } 
    fputs(string, output);
    fclose(output);
    return ix;
}

int fputsArray_b( unsigned size, int*  array , const char* filename)
{
    unsigned ix = 0; // bytes written
    FILE*    output = fopen( filename, "w");
    if ( output == NULL ) return -1;
    // file is open
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+= 1)
        ix += fprintf( output, "%d\n", array[i]);
    fclose(output);
    return ix;
}
```

The program writes 2 identical files...